# Does Google Guava Cache load on same thread?

Tags: multithreading, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

Does Google Guava Cache load the cache on the same thread by default?

Code:

```
cache = CacheBuilder
    .newBuilder()
    .refreshAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build(new CacheLoader<String,String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(String s) throws Exception {
            return addCache(s);
        }
});
```

Will the call to `addCache` be made on a different thread? As far as I know, it is a synchronous call but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple test allowing to know:

```
    System.out.println("Thread.currentThread() = " + Thread.currentThread());
    LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder
        .newBuilder()
        .refreshAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String load(String s) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Thread.currentThread() = " + Thread.currentThread());
                return "world";
            }
        });
    cache.get("hello");
```

Output:

```
Thread.currentThread() = Thread[main,5,main]
Thread.currentThread() = Thread[main,5,main]
```

Of course, as the documentation indicates, if another thread has already started loading the value for the key, the current thread won't reload it: it will wait for the value to be loaded by the other one:

> If another call to get(K) or getUnchecked(K) is currently loading the value for key, simply waits for that thread to finish and returns its loaded value.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I had written this test and it did return the same thread ids. But the documentation confused me a bit. I thought that I was not using the cache properly. So, just to be clear, we need to overload `CacheLoader.reload` for the call to be asynchronous, right?

Comment: Its quite late to answer , but yes you have to overload it for your CacheLoader.

Answer (score 2):

To add to JB Nizet's answer, you can find out why Guava avoids making the cache multi-threaded by default [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen):

> The reason for this is as follows: if we wanted to perform Cache maintenance continuously, we would need to create a thread, and its operations would be competing with user operations for shared locks. Additionally, some environments restrict the creation of threads, which would make CacheBuilder unusable in that environment.